# simultaneous equations with greater than 2 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In an introductory course to matrices I learned:

If we have two equations:
$$ax+by=c$$
$$dx+fy=g$$
then this can be represented as:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
d & f
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
c \\
g
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and therefore the values for $x$ and $y$ can be calculated:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{af-bd}
\begin{pmatrix}
f & -b \\
-d & a
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c \\
g
\end{pmatrix}
$$
from this we can then obtain general formulas for what $x$ and $y$ are equal to. My question is can this be done for a greater number of variables (Inverse of higher order matrices is more difficult) and if so are these general formulas known?

Comment: also does the formatting on these matrices look okay, I have never done it in mathjax before

Comment: Yeah looks just fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!
Take a look at [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule).
It states that using the determinant of the coefficient matrix and determinants of matrices where on column is replaced with the $b$ vector (in $Ax=b$), one could find a general solution to the linear system of equations.
This still requires calculating determinants, which can be difficult in the general case, but is definitely easier than finding inverses.

Comment: my understanding from this is that if we have a system of equations satisfied by: $$AX=B$$ then $$X=A^{-1}B=\frac{\text{adj}(A)}{\det(A)}B$$. Is this what I should use for the general solutions?

Comment: Well, yes, if $A$ is invertible then $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}\operatorname{adj} A$ but that's not what Cramer's rule states. The rule states that if you want to find the solution to $Ax=b$ then simply set $x_i=\frac{\det A_i}{\det A}$ where $A_i$ is achieved by replacing the $i$-th column of $A$ with $b$, and $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ will be your solution.

Comment: ah you mean the bit under the "applications" section. I see now. So all I need to know is how to find the determinant of each matrix produced

Comment: Yeah. Also I mean the bit under `General Case`, `Applications` just gives some small examples.